# Gradle task executed as a different user

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle task set up to run a Java class:

```
task runEchoServerTest(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: [compileTestJava]) {
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    main = 'EchoServerTest'
}
```

But I want to run it as superuser, and don't want to type `sudo gradle runEchoServerTest`. Can the running user be changed within Gradle? Is this question stupid?

**Update:**

Following @NikitaSkvortsov's suggestion, I add this task:

```
task sudoRunEchoServerTest(type: Exec, dependsOn: [compileTestJava]) {
    commandLine "sudo " + tasks.runEchoServerTest.commandLine.join(" ")
}
```

I did not add a password, because I am working on a Raspberry Pi, where `sudo` can be used without a password.

I run that task, but it failed. To find out more, I run it again with `--stacktrace`. Here is the key message (edited for easier reading):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "sudo /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java 
-Djava.library.path=./native/linux 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Duser.country=GB 
-Duser.language=en 
-Duser.variant 
-cp /home/pi/bloomm/build/classes/java/main:/home/pi/bloomm/build/resources/main:/home/pi/bloomm/build/classes/java/test:/home/pi/bloomm/build/resources/test EchoServerTest" 
(in directory "/home/pi/bloomm"): 
error=2, No such file or directory
```

The funny thing is, if I copy that entire command to the command line and run it, it works!

So, where else could it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call `su` or `sudo` anyway, because one can not simply change the current user of a process in OS :)

To do so, add one more exec task, get the effective command line of pre-configured java exec and prepend "sudo". Do not forget to supply the password!

```
task doPriveleged(type: Exec, dependsOn: [compileTestJava]) {
    commandLine "echo $sudo_password | sudo -S " + tasks.runEchoServerTest.commandLine.join(" ")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @NikitaSkvortsov. I was in the mindset of process management tools (such as systemd) where I can specify by which user a process is supposed to be run. Those tools are themselves run as root. That's why they can switch users. You remind me that Gradle is not such a tool and cannot simply change user, now I understand. Anyway, I follow your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. I have updated my original question to include additional experiences. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @NickLee sorry, I do not have a Raspberry Pi at hand, so it is hard to reproduce the problem. Try using slightly modifide `commadLine` value like this: 

`commandLine "sudo", tasks.runEchoServerTest.commandLine.join(" ")`

Comment: That still failed. But it's ok. It's a small problem not worth spending any more time on. Appreciate your help anyway.